# Как найти индексы (размеры) статического двумерного массива C++?

Tags: c++

Если в С++ дан массив int A[4][5], как можно узнать его первый индекс и второй? Чтобы объяснить вопрос приведу аналогию питоном. Если есть массив l=[[1,1],[2,2]], мы можем узнать кол-во элементов в нем функцией len(l), а кол-во элементов в первом элементе массива соответственно len(l[0]).

Comment: `sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0])` и `sizeof(A[0]) / sizeof(A[0][0])`. [Или](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size) `std::size(A)` и `std::size(A[0])`.

Comment: Или `constexpr std::size_t rows{4}, cols{5}; int A[rows][cols];`, тогда количество элементов — это `rows` и `cols` :)

Comment: Ну и для полноты, еще есть `std::extent_v<decltype(A)>` (первый индекс), `std::extent_v<decltype(A), 1>` или `std::extent_v<std::remove_reference_t<decltype(A[0])>>` (второй индекс).

Comment: ширина каждой строки массива фиксирована при компиляции. просто передавайте переменной эту ширину. точный ответ будет если вы покажете свою попытку.